# Mudando posição de diversas DIVS com mesmo seletor em Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, array, each

tenho uma página que contém diversas estruturas com um mesmo seletor, como:

```
<div class="preco">
R$ 69,90
</div>

<div class="preco-a-vista">
R$ 50,00
</div>
```

Como mencionei, a estrutura acima se repete diversas vezes na página. Eu preciso colocar o conteúdo da `div.preco-a-vista` dentro da `div.preco`

Fiz o seguinte código:

```
$('.preco-avista').each(function() {  
  var $this = $(this);
  $('.preco').append($($this).html());
});
```

Este código funciona, mas ele pega todos os preços da pagina (da div preco-a- vista) e coloca em todas div preco. Repetindo tudo. Poderiam me ajudar com esta dúvida?

Comment: Quando colocares o conteudo de `.preco-a-vista` dentro de `.preco` o que acontece a `.preco-a-vista`? fica duplicado ou é para remover?

Comment: É para remover sérgio! E atualmente no código está ficando..

Answer (score 1):

Não entendi muito bem sua pergunta, mas...

`$('.preco-a-vista').each((i,e) => {
  $('.preco').eq(i).html(e.textContent);
})`

Comment: Não funcionou :-|
Então Rafael a ideia é basicamente colocar a div preco-a-vista dentro da div preco. O problema é que estas divs se repetem (com o mesmo seletor) por toda página. Com o código que coloquei acima, funciona, mas todas DIV preco-a-vista são inseridas em todas divs preco.

Answer (score 1):

Fiz a função bem simples e coloquei a explicação comentando as linhas de códigos.
Mas, resumindo:

***1.*** Conta os elementos com classe "preco-a-vista" na pagina;

***2.*** Cada um desses elementos é colocado dentro do elemento com classe "preco" na mesma ordem;

***3.*** Os elementos "preco-a-vista" são apagados

```js
$(function(){
  //pega a quantidade de elementos
  var vista = $(".preco-a-vista");
  var qntVista = vista.length;

  //função para remover os elementos após a execução
  function removerVista(){
    $(".preco-a-vista").remove(); 
  }

  // colocar os 'preco-a-vista' dentro do 'preco'
  for (j = 0; j < qntVista; j++){
    var htmlVista = $(".preco-a-vista:eq("+j+")").html();
    $(".preco:eq("+j+")").append(htmlVista);
  }

  // executa a função de remover os 'preco-a-vista'
  removerVista();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="preco">
R$ 69,90
</div>
<div class="preco-a-vista">
R$ 50,00
</div>

<div class="preco">
R$ 79,90
</div>
<div class="preco-a-vista">
R$ 60,00
</div>

<div class="preco">
R$ 89,90
</div>
<div class="preco-a-vista">
R$ 80,00
</div>

<div class="preco">
R$ 99,90
</div>
<div class="preco-a-vista">
R$ 150,00
</div>

<div class="preco">
R$ 429,90
</div>
<div class="preco-a-vista">
R$ 200,00
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado VME! Deu certo!

Comment: Grato em ajudar! Pode marcar esta resposta como a resposta para a pergunta!

Answer (score 1):

Seria assim?

`$('.preco-a-vista').each((i,e) => {
  $('.preco').eq(i).appendTo($(e).html()); 
})`

Nesse caso é para números iguais de div '.preco-a-vista' e .'preco'.
Existe N formas de fazer. Ai estamos movendo a div.preco-a-vista para dentro da div.preco, porem, mantendo o texto da mesma. Se quiser apenas substituir o conteúdo, use o append.